# dynamic array to local storage/jstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, jstorage

I am pushing values in to my array every 10 seconds which is being displayed by innerHTML on a div.

Onreload or on visit to some other web page I want to display the already pushed content and the content being pushed presently.
I have gone through local stroage and jstorage tutorials.

This is what I am doing precisely=:

```
localStorage.setItem('names', xyz);
```

I know how to store one variable,but what when we have a dynamic array being updated/10sec and data being pushed in it every 10 seconds.how do I set and get this **dynamic array** even when I go to some other link.

If you are interested in my code:http://jsfiddle.net/vCcnB/

**UPDATE 1----for simplification(ignore if you have understood.)**
This is what is being displayed in my div.Page1 indicates the page and 0,10,20 indicates time.

```
@ 10 seconds----[page1,0]
                [page1,10]

@20 seconds-----[page1,0]
                [page1,10]
                [page1,20]
    now a click to some other page.

@10 seconds----[page1,0]
               [page1,10]
               [page1,20]
               [page2,0]
               [page2,10]
    now a click to some other page.

@20 seconds----[page1,10]
               [page1,20]
               [page2,0]
               [page2,10]
               [page3,0]
               [page3,10]
               [page3,20]
```

Comment: What you mean by other link ? other domain ?

Comment: localhost/project/home.php to localhost/project/contact_us.php(just an example)

Comment: what about `localStorage.getItem()` ?

Comment: I dont know how to use them?

Comment: Can you show us some example data ? and what do you need to do if same data comes in ?

Comment: I will just update my question ?just give me two min

Comment: @Red:updated!!!have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json object` for this like,

```
localStorage.setItem('names', {'ABC','XYZ'}); //and so on
```

or `json string` like

```
var json={'ABC','XYZ'};
localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(json)); //and so on
```

To **get** an existing **item** try this,

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('names'));
```

Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage

Comment: can you have a look at my code,you will understand what i am trying to achieve.The data comes from php page in json encoded form every 10 seconds.so how do i set it and retrieve it back  on some othe page

Comment: console.log(localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(json))) is undefined?

Comment: Use `getItem` like `console.log(localStorage.getItem('names'));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to JSON.stringify and JSON.parse your array to store and load it respectively.

```
// initialize
var myArray = [];
// load saved array
if(window.localStorage["savedArray"] != null)
    myArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage["savedArray"]);
// modify array
myArray.push("abc123");
// re-save array
window.localStorage["savedArray"] = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```