# Check if a value from localStorage startsWith a string and console.log() value name

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a question that's maybe hard to explain... But I'll try my best to.
So, I have in localStorage like 3 value and I can't know their name. Let's say there's a, b and c. A value is equal to "Good morning", B value to "Good afternoon", and C value to "Bad night". I want to console.log() if A value, B value or C value startsWith() "Good". And so I don't really know how to do it...
Anyone can help me? Thanks.
Demo.

Comment: Here is the answer smilar problem like you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193115/4582992](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193115/4582992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the localstorage and check their values

```
for (var i = 0, i < localStorage.length; i++) {
   var value = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
   if (value && value.startsWith('Good') console.log('found it!', key, value);
}
```

Or more simply:

```
var valuesWithGood = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(x => localStorage.getItem(x).startsWith('Good')))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Second code worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your string **'Good afternoon'** as a param and it will iterate through local storage to check if it exists.

Using **Object.values()** method the function will return **true** if it matches the string passed to the function.

```
const findValue = (value) => Object.values(localStorage).indexOf(value) > -1;

console.log(findValue('Good afternoon')); // true
```

Alternativley if you need this to work in Internet Explorer browser we could use **Object.keys()** and **.some()**

```
const findValue = (value) => Object.keys(localStorage).some(key => (localStorage[key] === value));

console.log(findValue('Good afternoon')); // true
```

FYI: **startWith()** is not supported by Internet Explorer

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer but it doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: are you sure?, I have double checked the code and it is working, are you invoking the function with findValue('Good afternoon'), can you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: @demostanis I have added an alternative to work with Internet Explorer as **startWith()** method is not supported in IE

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome, not IE. In localStorage I defined "Hello" which is equal to "World". When I use your code (`findValue("World")`) It will return `true`. But I want to know if it _starts_ by for example `Wo`. And so I use your code like this: `findValue("Wo")` and it will return `false`.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp

there is startswith function in javascript try it!

Answer (score -2):

Уоu can do something like:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(x) {
    if( x === 'someValue_1' ||
        x === 'someValue_2' ||
        x.startsWith('otherValue_')
    ){
        console.log(x);
    }
});
```